# DCGAN producing noise but not expected structure, Can someone help me get proper results out of a DCGAN?

Tags: python, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

Can someone help me get proper results/images from my DCGAN ?

I'm getting different colored (noise) pictures from one
iteration to another, but not anywhere close to what I should
get. I'm feeding Human faces/Cats/Dogs with labels to train my generator
and discriminator, and I should get output that looks
either like a Cat or Dog or human face.

I'm getting different results/pixels for different latent vector
values, and different colors for different iterations but not in
the structure of faces or animals.

I'm using Binary cross-entropy loss function for
generator, discriminator and gan. I tried using MAE in
addition to cross entropy for generator but didn't get anything
different. I tried training generator and discriminator
together, separately, and alternate epoch for generator and
discriminator but nothing good came out from these attempts either .
I'm running this for more than 700 epochs(5 days) with each
iteration taking over 5 minutes on CPU.

```
def generator(latent_dim, n_classes):
    
    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.021)
    in_label = Input(shape=(1,))
    li = Embedding(n_classes, 25)(in_label)
    n_nodes = 64 * 64
    
    li = Dense(n_nodes)(li)
    
    li = Reshape((64, 64, 1))(li)
    
    
    in_lat = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    n_nodes = 128 * 64 * 64
    
    gen = Dense(n_nodes)(in_lat)
    
    gen = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(gen)
    gen = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(gen)
    gen = Reshape((64, 64, 128))(gen)

    merge = Concatenate()([gen, li])
    gen = Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same',kernel_initializer=initializer,use_bias=False)(merge)
    gen = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(gen)
    gen = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(gen)
    

    gen = Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same',kernel_initializer=initializer,use_bias=False)(gen)
    gen = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(gen)
    gen = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(gen)

    
    out_layer = Conv2D(3, (7,7), activation='tanh', padding='same',kernel_initializer=initializer,use_bias=False)(gen)
    model = Model([in_lat, in_label], out_layer, name="generator")
    
    opt = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics='accuracy')
    
    return model



def define_discriminator(n_classes,in_shape=(256,256,3)):
    
    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.021)
    in_label = Input(shape=(1,))
    li = Embedding(n_classes, 25)(in_label)     
    n_nodes = in_shape[0] * in_shape[1]
    
    li = Dense(n_nodes)(li)

    li = Reshape((in_shape[0], in_shape[1],1))(li)
    
    in_image = Input(shape=in_shape)
    merge = Concatenate()([in_image, li])
    
    fe = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same',kernel_initializer=initializer,use_bias=False)(merge)
    fe = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(fe)
    fe = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(fe)

    fe = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same',kernel_initializer=initializer,use_bias=False)(fe)
    fe = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(fe)
    fe = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(fe)
    
    
    fe = Flatten()(fe)
    fe = Dropout(0.4)(fe)

    out_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(fe)
    model = Model([in_image, in_label], out_layer, name="discriminator")

    opt = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model



def define_gan(g_model, d_model):
    
    g_model.trainable = True
    d_model.trainable = False
    
    gen_noise, gen_label = g_model.input
    gen_output = g_model.output
    
    gan_output = d_model([gen_output, gen_label])
    model = Model([gen_noise, gen_label], gan_output, name="gan")
    opt = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt,  loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics='accuracy')
    return model
```

Below are the results/images for different iterations. 16 squares are 16
different latent vectors seed.

[image: Results of epoch 700]

[image: Results of epoch 701]

[image: Results of epoch 704]

[image: Results of epoch 708]

Comment: Try removing accuracy from compile. This is a DCGAN example for keras using faces, https://keras.io/examples/generative/dcgan_overriding_train_step/.

Comment: Thanks for responding...I will try as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code it's hard to speculate, but you can check [this repo](https://github.com/the-deep-learners/deep-learning-illustrated/blob/master/notebooks/generative_adversarial_network.ipynb) out for reference.

Pay attention to this note:

Separately, for reasons that escape us, the discriminator in this notebook nearly always fails to learn if you train on a CPU only. Because of this failure, the GAN will seldom learn how to generate sketches -- i.e., it will output images that are merely random noise. There are two ways we've identified to remedy this situation:

1. Use a GPU. If you don't have one, use Colab as suggested above. While in Colab, you can select "Change runtime type" from the "Runtime" item in the menu bar, and choose "GPU" as your hardware accelerator. This hardware accelerator trains the GAN orders of magnitude more rapidly than the "None" or "TPU" options, and the discriminator (we have no idea why!) will train properly.
2. Change the discriminator's optimizer. As noted by a comment in this notebook's discriminator compilation step, switching from the default RMSprop optimizer to another (e.g., Adam or AdaDelta) enables the discriminator to learn effectively and therefore the GAN generates sketches. Whether you use a CPU only, a GPU, or a TPU, this solution is effective. (That said, training the GAN with a GPU is still way faster than with a CPU only or a TPU.)

You can also look into this discussion: https://github.com/the-deep-learners/deep-learning-illustrated/issues/2

Comment: Hi tromgy, thanks for responding...the problem is not with the discriminator but with the generator. Discriminator is classifying fake and real images perfectly and I'm already using adam optimizer as you see it in my code. Anyhow, as you suggested I will try using a different optimizer for discriminator, may be a SGD, not to improve it's performance but to give generator some space to learn.   thank you.